# How to enable CSV or PDF export in material-react-table using TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, export-to-csv, material-react-table

is there a way to add the option of export to CSV or PDF on a material-react-table? I know how to add those options in the material UI table, but I don't find the same option for the material-react-table

Thanks

Export to CSV or PDF a material-react-table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example [guide](https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/examples/data-export) to do exactly that on their documentation. Here is the [link to the code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/github/KevinVandy/material-react-table/tree/main/apps/material-react-table-docs/examples/export-to-csv/sandbox) from the documents.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I implement it and it worked!